# Javascript - remove one element using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am not quite familiar with JavaScript, so I am stuck.
I need to remove first class element from the page.

I found this script which removes all class elements, but i need to remove the first one only.

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Links");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, function(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

So tried this trick which  did not do its magic

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0];
```

also tried but withou results

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Links");
var requiredElement = collection[0];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(requiredElement, function(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

so probably something should be with this line.

```
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".Links").remove()`

Answer (score 1):

In that `forEach` callback function, `node` is simply each element in the collection.  But since you now have a single element instead of a collection of elements, you can just perform that operation on that element:

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Links");
var requiredElement = collection[0];
requiredElement.parentNode.removeChild(requiredElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector(".Links").remove();
```

```html
<div class="Links">1</div>
<div class="Links">2</div>
```

and since `querySelector` returns the first match (if exists) than `.remove()` will remove only that first element.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work because for each works on array/array like structures. One single element is not array like structure.
You can do like this:

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Links");
var node = collection[0];
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box'), //catch all desired elements
    parent = document.getElementById('parent'); //catch the parent element

    parent.removeChild(elems[0]); //remove the first element from the parent
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if need to remove the first 'links' class element from the whole page

```
       if (document.getElementsByClassName('links').length > 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('links')[0].remove();
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  remove_first_element("hello");
});
function remove_first_element(class_name)
{
     var i=0;
     $("."+class_name).each(function(){
        if(i==0)
        {
           $(this).remove();
           i++;
         }
     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello">hello 1</div>
<div class="hello">hello 2</div>
```